# ExpressJS - Wrong domain name in request headers

Tags: node.js, express

I have multiple domains pointing to same server. when i'm try to print the host name using `req.headers['theHost']` it shows the other domain name instead of one to which request is sent. Example if i request a.com then in the headers it is showing b.com(other domain pointing to same server).

Comment: You may want to provide more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the hostname of an incoming request you can use `req.get('Host');` (Express v4 way to get headers from a request - header field is case insensitive).